# How do I create sidebar menu with sub menus using dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create sidebar menu with dynamic data where menu contains 1 or 2 submenus.

```
menuList: [
        {
            "permission_id": 1,
            "menu_hierarchy": "01",
            "menu_name": "DashBoard",
            "menu_code": "M001",
            "menu_link": "/",
            "menu_order": 1,
            "is_enabled": 1,
            "application_type": 1
        },
        {
            "permission_id": 2,
            "menu_hierarchy": "02",
            "menu_name": "Search",
            "menu_code": "M002",
            "menu_link": "/",
            "menu_order": 1,
            "is_enabled": 1,
            "application_type": 1
        },
        {
            "permission_id": 2,
            "menu_hierarchy": "0202",
            "menu_name": "Synonyms",
            "menu_code": "M002.S002",
            "menu_link": "/synonyms",
            "menu_order": 1,
            "is_enabled": 1,
            "application_type": 1
        },
        {
            "permission_id": 5,
            "menu_hierarchy": "04",
            "menu_name": "RolesPermissions",
            "menu_code": "M004",
            "menu_link": "/",
            "menu_order": 1,
            "is_enabled": 1,
            "application_type": 1
        },
        {
            "permission_id": 8,
            "menu_hierarchy": "0401",
            "menu_name": "Users",
            "menu_code": "M004.S001",
            "menu_link": "/userslist",
            "menu_order": 1,
            "is_enabled": 1,
            "application_type": 1
        },
        {
            "permission_id": 12,
            "menu_hierarchy": "0402",
            "menu_name": "Roles",
            "menu_code": "M004.S002.U001",
            "menu_link": "/roles",
            "menu_order": 1,
            "is_enabled": 1,
            "application_type": 1
        }
      ]
```

in the above object M002 means mainmenu M002.S002 means sub menu, I'm able create main menu, but struck in creating sub menu.

```
<ul class="metismenu list-unstyled" id="side-menu">
          <li v-for="menu in menuList" :key="menu">
            <router-link tag="a" :to="menu.menu_link" class="side-nav-link">
              <i class="ti-home"></i>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary float-right">2</span>
              <span>{{menu.menu_name}}</span>
            </router-link>
          </li>
</ul>
```

If menu_code has single "." means I want to include it in the sub menu level 1, if menu_code has two "."means I want to include it in the sub menu level 2.

```
"menu_code": "M002.S002",
```

Example:

```
- RolesPermissions
     - users
         - roles
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this out  and change your data structure in that manner 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320415/vue-js-dropdown-nested-menu-keep-parent-open-when-child-active

Comment: As @Amaarrockz implies, your structure isn't conducive to creating submenus; you'd be better off transforming the structure of the data before creating the menus (ie. by using a `computed` property).